# ckeditor content is not showing properly in front end in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, ckeditor5

I stored CKEditor content in a database. My content is consist of text image and table. The data is stored in the database perfectly as I used long text data type with the column. When I fetch and display the content on the front end, the textual content is displayed properly but the image is not showing and table borders are also not showing. I searched a lot but couldn't found the solution. I need the solution as soon as possible.